# Django ORM: need list of values with max ID for each value

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

My table looks roughly like this:

```
ID | DISPLAY | CATEGORY | NAME
1  |  true   |    1     | some name
2  |  true   |    1     | some other name
3  |  true   |    1     | some name
4  |  true   |    2     | something else
```

I want a result set that would give me the name and max ID for a given category and display = true, so in SQL form:

```
select name, max(id) as recent
from TABLE
where category = 1 and display = true
```

And I have done this as:

```
rs = TABLE.objects.filter(category=1, display=True).values('name').annotate(recent=Max('id'))
```

But I'm getting a random id, not the maximum ID. 
Why is that? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your django query return a list of grouped column "name" and the max_id for this group.
In your example, the result is:

`Queryset({'name':'some name', recent="3"},{'name':'some other name', recent="2"})`

If you need the max_id with these filters, you can use `aggregate` function:

`rs = TABLE.objects.filter(category=1, display=True).aggregate(recent=Max('id'))`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. It doesn't give me a list of tasks, it just gives me the absolute max of the query.